# switchMap not trigger when LiveData changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I followed this documentation: [Transformations | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).switchMap(kotlin.Function1))

The idea is that when the value of `currentList` changes, the data of `activeTasks`, `completedTasks` and `importantTasks` will be automatically updated and then the observers will update the UI.

The problem I'm having is that when the value of `currentList` changes, the switchMaps that I have assigned to the LiveData are not triggered at all.

I tried to find the solution but i don't know exactly how to google about this problem.

here's my ViewModel:

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    companion object {
        const val TAG: String = "AppViewModel"
    }

    private val dataSource: TaskDao

    val lists: LiveData<List<TaskList>>
    var lastAction: Int = 1
    val currentList = MutableLiveData(1)

    var currentIndex: Int = -1
        set(value) {
            field = value
            Log.d(TAG, "currentIndex setter: index = $field")
        }

    init {
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(application)
        dataSource = db.taskDao()
        lists = dataSource.getAllLists()
    }

    fun importantTasks(): LiveData<List<Task>> = currentList.switchMap {
//      this line for tracking changes
//      and this how i know it not getting triggered
        Log.d(TAG, "importantTasks: updated")

        dataSource.getImportant(it)
    }

    fun activeTasks(): LiveData<List<Task>> = currentList.switchMap {
        Log.d(TAG, "activeTasks: updated")
        dataSource.getActiveTasks(it)
    }

    fun completedTasks(): LiveData<List<Task>> = currentList.switchMap {
        Log.d(TAG, "completedTasks: updated")
        dataSource.getCompletedTasks(it)
    }

    fun setCurrentList(id: Int){
        currentList.value = id
    }

    fun upsert(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        task.listId = currentList.value!!
        dataSource.upsert(task)
        Log.d(TAG, "upsert: task upserted at ${task.listId}")
    }

    fun delete(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        task.listId = currentList.value!!
        dataSource.delete(task)
        Log.d(TAG, "delete: task deleted at ${task.listId}")
    }

    fun upsertList(list: TaskList) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        dataSource.upsertList(list)
        Log.d(TAG, "upsertList: updated: id = ${list.id} , name = ${list.name}")
    }
}
```

here's how i change the value of `currentList`:

```
    override fun onItemClicked(id: Int) {
        viewModel.setCurrentList(id)
        dismiss()
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this on a new project to test if the problem was me but it works perfectly fine.

the viewmodel:

```
class AppViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val listId = MutableLiveData(0)

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> = listId.switchMap {
        Log.d("AppViewModel", "getUsers: updated")
        data(it)
    }

    fun data(id: Int): LiveData<List<User>> {
        val users = if (id == 0) List(30) { i -> User(i, "User$i", "password$i") }
        else List(25) { i -> User(i, "User$i", "password$i") }
        return MutableLiveData(users)
    }
}
```

how i changed the value of `listId`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    val viewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textCounter)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonSwitch)

        viewModel.getUsers().observeForever{
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate: observer triggered")
            text.text = "${it.size}"
        }
        button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.listId.value = if (viewModel.listId.value == 1) 0 else 1
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using RoomDatabase for the first project, maybe that the cause of my problem(not sure about that) because in the second one I use a specific data set and it works ok.

Comment: You have to `observe` the LiveData returned by `switchMap` for it to actually do anything. Where do you observe each of those LiveDatas?

Comment: I put the observer in a fragment for each, the `switchMap` does trigger when init `currentList` but not getting triggered any more when i change the `currentList` value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The problem cause by define 2 different instance of viewmodels in 2 different places (MainActivity and a fragment inside ViewPager2 in this case)
How i define the viewmodels:

```
val viewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()
```

and i thought that they used the same `context` and when i change the value in MainActivity, the fragment will notice that but no. Even though the fragment is inside the Activity, they used different context(i think). Here how i solved the problem:

- in MainActivity:

```
val viewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()
```

- in the fragment:

```
lateinit var viewModel: AppViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(): View {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(AppViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Have a nice day!!